# Upgraded NHibernate and FNH DLLs - now getting "No persister" exceptions

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to upgrade my FNH Automapping project to the latest versions of NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate (NH 3.2 and FNH 1.3), but now I get a "no persister" exception on a derived class (though the base class still seems to be persisted properly).

This derived class Automapped fine with the old dlls (FNH 1.0, NH 2.1.2) - I have not changed my mapping logic or these classes in any way.

I upgraded my project by just copying the new dlls over the old ones, and deleting references to dlls that are no longer needed (e.g. Antlr 3, Castle) by the new dlls.

Exact versions I'm using:

NHibernate         3.2.0.4000
FluentNHibernate   1.3.0.0
System.Data.SQLite 1.0.76.0
VS 2008            9.0.30729.1 SP
Windows XP SP3 (32 bit)

The mapping code that works with the old dlls, but not with the new ones:

```
            return AutoMap.Assemblies(_assemblies)
                // Don't map the abstract base class
                .IgnoreBase<OfeEntity>()

                // Only map subclasses of OfeEntity
                .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(OfeEntity)))

                .Conventions.Add(
                    // Do cascading saves on all entities so lists  will be
                    // automatically saved 
                    DefaultCascade.All(),

                    // Turn on lazy loading, so will only read data that is actually
                    // displayed
                    DefaultLazy.Always()
                );
```

**Edit:**

After turning FNH Diagnostics on, I can see that FNH is not creating a table for my derived class with the new dlls.

Also, one thing I noticed - the class that is not being persisted is subclassed by 2 levels.  That is, I have a the following classes:

```
public abstract class OfeEntity

public class OfeMeasurementBase : OfeEntity

public class OfeDlsMeasurement : OfeMeasurementBase
```

OfeDlsMeasurement is the class that is not being persisted. OfeMeasurementBase, as well as several other classes that inherit from OfeEntity, are being persisted properly.

Old versions had no problem with this - maybe new versions have a bug when there's more than one level of inheritance?

Comment: When is this exception encountered?  When building your session factory?

Comment: Got the exception when tried to do SaveOrUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

I migrated our project from some older (F)NH to the latest NH 3.2. I suspect it now uses different key field names in collections and such, because I need to specify exact column names when using the existing database.

Also, I suggest rebuilding Fluent NHibernate from sources with NHibernate 3.2 just to be sure everything gets in the place.

Answer (score 1):

The article  [How to upgrade your apps to NHibernate 3.2 with Fluent NHibernate 1.2](http://joao.manso.eu/index.php/2011/08/how-to-upgrade-your-apps-to-nhibernate-3-2-with-fluent-nhibernate-1-2/) may be helpful. I used it myself to upgrade a project and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, wish I'd found that article when I started this! One question - do I really need to explicitly set the default proxy factory? Tried this, and got "Unable to find DefaultProxyFactoryFactory" compile error.

Comment: This seems to be necessary. In my project I get an "invalid or incomplete configuration" exception when I leave it out. I think Fluent uses the _NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle_ as default and this is no longer included with 3.2