# NHibernate 3.2 - Do all properties now require a "set" method?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

We recently upgraded our Automapped FNH / NH project to NH 3.2, and are running into a lot of problems.

We have a lot of properties in our object model that only have a "getter", e.g.

```
    public virtual float Polydispersity
    {
        get { return MeasurementRun.PolyDispersity; }
    }
```

This used to work fine, but now we get "Could not find a setter for property" errors.

This was hard to find, because for some reason the automapping was silently failing to create the DB tables, leading to "no persister" errors when saving to the DB - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8041881/102554) for details.

Is this because LinFu is now built into NH?  I know private setters no longer work, and this seems to be a similar problem.

We used to use Castle, and I really like that NH doesn't require all those other DLLs now, but not if it breaks a big part of our object model.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

**Stack Trace**

> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or
>   incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.
>   Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>
> ---> NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter
>   for property 'Polydispersity' in class
>   'BI_OverlordDlsAppCore.OfeDlsMeasurement'    at
>   NHibernate.Properties.BasicPropertyAccessor.GetSetter(Type type,
>   String propertyName)    at NHibernate.Mapping.Property.GetSetter(Type
>   clazz)    at
>   NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer.BuildPropertySetter(Property
>   mappedProperty, PersistentClass mappedEntity)    at
>   NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer..ctor(EntityMetamodel
>   entityMetamodel, PersistentClass mappingInfo)    at
>   NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer..ctor(EntityMetamodel
>   entityMetamodel, PersistentClass mappedEntity)    at
>   NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping..ctor(PersistentClass
>   mappedEntity, EntityMetamodel em)    at
>   NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.EntityMetamodel..ctor(PersistentClass
>   persistentClass, ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)    at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister..ctor(PersistentClass
>   persistentClass, ICacheConcurrencyStrategy cache,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)    at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister..ctor(PersistentClass
>   persistentClass, ICacheConcurrencyStrategy cache,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, IMapping mapping)    at
>   NHibernate.Persister.PersisterFactory.CreateClassPersister(PersistentClass
>   model, ICacheConcurrencyStrategy cache, ISessionFactoryImplementor
>   factory, IMapping cfg)    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping
>   mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)    at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()    at
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()    at
>   BI_OverlordPackageCore.OfeDatabase.CreateSqliteSessionFactory() in
>   C:\Bicw_Dev\Bic.Net\Private Projects\NHibernate\FNH 1.3 Mapping
>   Bug\OfeDatabase.cs:line 192    at
>   BI_OverlordPackageCore.OfeDatabase.GetMainSession() in
>   C:\Bicw_Dev\Bic.Net\Private Projects\NHibernate\FNH 1.3 Mapping
>   Bug\OfeDatabase.cs:line 147    at
>   BI_OverlordPackageCore.OfeDatabase.Initialize(Assembly[] assemblies)
>   in C:\Bicw_Dev\Bic.Net\Private Projects\NHibernate\FNH 1.3 Mapping
>   Bug\OfeDatabase.cs:line 305    at
>   FNH_1._3_Mapping_Bug.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in C:\Bicw_Dev\Bic.Net\Private Projects\NHibernate\FNH 1.3 Mapping
>   Bug\Form1.cs:line 23    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: I'm using NHibernate 3.2.0.GA with many get-only-properties and it works fine. Please post the full exception message and stack trace.

Comment: @cremor - I added the stack trace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You should not map readonly properties.**

**- Solution 1**

```
    var map = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Dummy>()
         .OverrideAll(x => x.IgnoreProperties(property => !property.CanWrite));
```

**- Solution 2**

```
internal class MyMappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
        public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
        {
            return base.ShouldMap(member) && member.CanWrite;
        }
}
```

... Then use your conf :

```
var map = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Dummy>(new MyMappingConfiguration());
```

*Edit : Added Tom Bushell's suggestion*

Comment: Thanks - I may be able to use this as a workaround, though I found it more convenient to do this as an override in my AutoMap call       i.e. .OverrideAll(map => map.IgnoreProperties(prop => !prop.CanWrite).  This eliminates the exception in my sample project, but the mapping still fails silently in my real project.